# Laravel - Send email on specific event

Tags: laravel

I am currently developing an API, and each click is counted, with an api consumption.
When 80% of the api is consumed, I would like to send an email alert to the user.

I don't know this whole aspect of Laravel yet, and I'd like to know how you would do that? If possible by detailing a minimum

Thank you in advance,

Comment: Rate limiter? Middleware?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that this information is available in your database.

If so, you could

1. [make an artisan command](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/artisan#writing-commands) which get all user with > 80% and
   notified = 0
2. Loop on those user and send the mail
3. Set notified to 1 on each user
4. Use CRON & [Laravel scheduler](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/scheduling#scheduling-artisan-commands) to call your command

*Don't forget to reset "notified" if necessary*

Comment: The information does not appear directly in the db, I make a calculation from all the apis (max consumption - consumption)

Comment: The email should be sent directly when the 80% is reached and not every X hours.